# Converting a CFG into Chomsky Normal form

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar, pumping-lemma, chomsky-normal-form

1. Using    the Pumping Lemma   for Regular Languages,  show    that    the

   language    L   =   {
   a<sup>i</sup>, b<sup>j</sup>
   c<sup>k</sup> | i,  j,  k   are non-negative    integers, and   i=j or  i=k
   }

is  not regular

2. Design CFG for the language above

This is what I came up with

```
Answer: G = (V,,R, S) with set of variables V = {S,W,X, Y,Z},
where S is the start variable; set of terminals  = {a, b, c}; and rules
S → XY | W
X → aXb | e
Y → cY | e
W → aWc | Z
Z → bZ | e
```

Now I have to convert the above CFG into chomsky normal form which I am having trouble with...any help?